# RecyclerView.Adapter appears to be disregarding the getItemCount method

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

When inserting a new image into the front of my RecyclerView my image is added to the front, however it appears that the image at the bottom of the view is then entirely disregarded. When displaying the results from getItemCount it is returning the correct size if a new image were to be added however this is appearing to be disregarded.

When a new image is added I call this code..

```
@Override
public void photoAdded()
{
    notifyItemInserted(0);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Is there anything I am missing? Is there some other way to force the adapter to take into account the fact that the itemCount has changed?

Bit of an update... I found that it begins to regard the new size once the phone has been locked and then unlocked!

Cheers!

Comment: Are you actually adding something to your data set additionally to calling `notifydataSetChanged`? And do you actually return a different size from `getItemCount` after the size changed?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Yep! So that photoAdded method is called as soon as the data set is updated, and yes! I've been logging the getItemCount and it appears to be changing size as soon as the new item is added! I just don't understand why the adapter is not reacting to it!

Comment: FYI, `notifyItemInserted` is a just a more specific version of `notifyDataSetChanged`, so you don't have to call both

Comment: @TheoKanning Thanks for the advice!